# PayPal transactions won't track properly in Google Analytics 4 using GTM implementation

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to track transactions in Google Analytics 4. I have two options on this ecommerce site for users to make payment - PayPal and credit card. The credit cart details fields are contained within an iFrame, so the user stays on the site. However, when paying with PayPal, it takes you off the site and to PayPal to complete your transaction, and then sends you back to the checkout success page. The issue is that none of the PayPal transactions track in GA4, but all of the credit card ones do.

So I have investigated this using the GA4 DebugView and GTM Tag Assistant. The datalayer is fine - there is nothing wrong with the datalayer for PayPal transactions. The problem is that even though the purchase event gets fired and all the datalayer variables are correct when the user comes back to the site after transacting with PayPal, the tag that sends purchase data back to GA4 does not fire. I am thinking this is possibly an ordering issue - that the datalayer is firing before the tag has loaded as a result of the user coming off the site - but I am not sure.

It is not a referral exclusion issue. The data does not get to Analytics for it to be filtered out in the first place - it is not an issue of payment gateway referral exclusions.

Comment: You don't need to guess. Use the GTM debugger, get your purchase event, select it, confirm that the tag doesn't fire, open it, go to its trigger and find what blocks it from firing. Add screenshots.